# Dismiss keyboard for UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have few text fields in a `UIViewController`. For some of the text fields I have used IBOutlet to make property. For some textFields that I add programmatically (since they are in scroll view, they are not in the constraints of the view controller window in soryboard. ) , I have just made them property without `IBOutlet`.

So for example, I have:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) **IBOutlet** UITextField *descriptionTextBox;

@property(strong , nonatomic) UITextField *cityTextField;
```

Now I set the delegates of both in `ViewDidLoad` & also in `.h` file `<UITextFieldDelegate>`

But after implementing `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` method , the keyboard only return for the text field having IBOutlet.**What can I do for it?**

```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
      [textField resignFirstResponder]; //works only for text field declared in storyBoard.

      return YES;
     }
```

Comment: Show the code where you create `cityTextField` and set its delegate.

Comment: self.cityTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 120, 20)]; & delegate in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: No, update your question with the actual code. Don't summarize, post real code showing the full creation of the text field and the setting of the delegate.

Comment: Is textField the same as cityTextField when you set a breakpoint in the textFieldShouldReturn call?

Comment: ok got it working...declared delegate in creation method only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view controller, say `[self.view endEditing:YES]`. This will dismiss the keyboard regardless of who is first responder.

Comment: This is more of a comment since it doesn't address the issue at hand.

Comment: It was intended to address the issue at hand, i.e. how to dismiss the keyboard when you failed to keep a reference to the current first-responder. The issue, as I understood it, is that you don't always know who the first responder is (which is itself, in my opinion, a huge bug in iOS).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be helpful to see more code.

However your issue could be that you're not setting the delegate on your UITextFields hence the method only being called on the one in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see whether you have set delegate to your UITextField objects that were created programatically.